# Convert time difference in milliseconds to formatted time

Tags: java, date, calendar, simpledateformat

Let's say I have the difference between two hours

```
java.text.DateFormat f = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
java.util.Date checkIn = f.parse("00:00");
java.util.Date checkOut = f.parse("05:00");

Long timeDifference = new Long(checkOut.getTime() - checkIn.getTime());
```

I can see how many hours this interval has by dividing "timeDifference" by 3600000 (one hour in milliseconds), and I get the correct result, 5.

But when I try to convert "timeDifference" like so:

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.setTime(new Date(timeDifference));
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
formatter.format(cal.getTime());
```

I get "02:00"... Why? How can I format "timeDifference"?

EDIT:
I don't really care about the dates. I just want the difference between checkIn and checkOut  in hoursformatted like HH:mm.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd.HH:mm:ss");
Date zeroDt = new Date(0);
System.out.println(format.format(zero));
```

you get:

```
1970-01-01.02:00:00
```

This date (January 1, 1970, 02:00) is the start of the axis.

Now try:

```
java.text.DateFormat f = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
Date checkIn = f.parse("00:00");
Date checkOut = f.parse("05:00");
System.out.println(checkIn.getTime());
System.out.println(checkOut.getTime());
```

You get:

```
-7200000
10800000
```

As you can see, checkIn is negative (-2 hours).
This is why checkOut.getTime() - checkIn.getTime() gives 5 hours - (-2 hours) = 7 hours.

You have to keep in mind that date.getTime() is negative for dates before 1970-01-01.02:00:00.

Answer (score 0):

> I get "02:00"... Why? How can I format "timeDifference"?

You are somewhat mis-using these classes.  My guess is you are in a Moscow time zone which was GMT+3 in 1970.

The simple answer is to use JoaTime which handles dates like this or just write your own parser and formatters which would be about the same amount of code.

Answer (score 0):

`cal.setTime(new Date(timeDifference)):` What you're doing here is setting the time to `timeDifference` (18000000) milliseconds after Jan 1, 1970 GMT. (If you were to change your SimpleDateFormat to show the date as well as the time, this would be apparent). You're getting 02:00 because that's what time it was in your time zone 18000000 milliseconds after midnight (GMT) on Jan 1, 1970. When I run your code (in California), it gives me 21:00, because we are 4 hours behind you.

It seems as though you're misunderstanding how the Calendar class works - see the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html). Beyond that, your question doesn't make it clear what exactly you are trying to accomplish. Hopefully with a better understanding of Calendar you'll be able to figure this out yourself - if not, edit your question and tell us exactly what Date you need.

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem here is that a time difference is not a date / timestamp.  It does not represent a "point in time".  The `DateFormat` interface ... and the classes that implement it are for formatting things that represent a point in time.

> I get "02:00"... Why?

What you get when you parse and unparse time values using a DataFormat is a date value for "today".  What happens is as follows:

1. "00:00" -> Is parsed as midnight today in the local time zone == t1 milliseconds since the epoch.
2. "05:00" -> Is parsed as 5am today in the local time zone = t2 milliseconds since the epoch.
3. t2 - t1 -> 5 hours (in milliseconds)
4. Date(t2 - t1) -> 5 hours after the epoch
5. (5 hours after the epoch) as a value in the local timezone is "1970-01-01T02:00:00"
6. Now throw away everything apart from the hours and minutes.

> How can I format "timeDifference"?

The simple way is to use `long` arithmetic to turn the time difference into integer hours and minutes, then format using `String.format(...)` or the equivalent using fixed width fields and zero padding.